# WebAPI with Windows Authentication returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: authentication, iis, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I'm designing a WebAPI service which is going to have to use windows authentication against a client's AD servers.  I'm trying to test this locally and am continually getting a 401 error, followed by the server just not allowing the request at all due to invalid credentials.  I'm doing my local tests in IIS 8.5 local (installed on a windows 8.1 box).  In IIS I have Windows Authentication enabled with the following providers:

- NTLM
- Negotiate
- Negotiate:Kerberos

In addition, I disabled kernel-mode authentication since IIS yells at me when I enable both kernel-mode and negotiate:kerberos.  Extended protection is also disabled.

In my config, I have my authorization rules set to allow all users, and authentication mode is set to "none":

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
```

Then in the controllers in the webapi, I'm putting the `[Authorize]` attribute on all controllers:

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Workorder")]
public class WorkorderController : ApiController
{
     ...
}
```

Can someone explain why I get the 401 challenge every time I attempt to access the API methods?

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**:
I changed `<authentication mode="None" />` to Windows, and that didn't help.  I also eliminated **NTLM** from my windows authentication providers since my machine is not on a domain so NTLM wouldn't work.

I also watched the request stream through fiddler and I'm able to see a series of 4 requests, each trying to authenticate using the **Negotiate** method and there appears to be kerberos tickets being passed back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem today. I changed Web API project properties, Anonymous Authentication as Enabled and Windows Authentication to disabled. and it worked like charm!

Comment: That simply disables Windows Authentication, which OP said they were using. If you remove the fire then obviously nothing's gonna burn.